# ngOptions not updating as objects added to array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, ng-options

I have an array which contains objects. When I push a new object to this list, the view does not update to add the new object. I assume it has to do with the $scope.$apply but I'm not sure how to use it. I've tried wrapping the push function around this but the factory says $scope is undefined.

View:

```
        <label for="groupOwner">List Template:
            <select 
                id="listTemplate"
                ng-model="newList.template"
                ng-options="t.name for t in listTemplates|orderBy: 'name'"
            ></select>
        </label>
```

Ctrl:

```
    $scope.createList = function (){
        var modalForm = '/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/partials/newList.html';   
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: modalForm,
            backdrop: true,
            windowClass: 'modal',
            controller: 'newListCtrl',
            resolve: {
                newListData: function (){
                    return $scope.newList;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function(newList){
            SiteService.createList(newList,$scope.site);
        });
    };
```

Service function:

```
var createList = function (newList, site){
    var promise = $().SPServices({
        operation: "AddList",
        webURL: site.url,
        listName: newList.name,
        description: newList.description,
        templateID: newList.template.id
    })

    promise.then(function (){
        addToQuickLaunch(newList.name,site.url)
        getSiteInfo(site);
        //take new list object and push to siteLists array
        siteLists.push(newList);
    },function (reason){
        console.log('Failed: ' + reason);
    })
}  

function addToQuickLaunch (name,siteUrl) {
    $().SPServices({
      operation: "UpdateList",
      webURL: siteUrl,
      listName: name,
      listProperties: "<List OnQuickLaunch='TRUE' EnableVersioning='TRUE'/>",
      completefunc: function(xData,Status){
        console.log(name + " list created")
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to show some more code: where is `siteLists` and `listTemplates` defined? Is the promise that `$().SPServices` returns based on Angular's $q implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code throws an immediate flag to me:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function(newList){
    SiteService.createList(newList,$scope.site);
});
```

You shouldn't pass the array from the controller through the service like that. Instead, do this:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function(newList){
    return SiteService.createList(newList);
}).then(function(list) {
  $scope.site.lists.push(list);
});
```

In this case, you'll have `createList` return a promise, and resolve that promise with the object that is to be added to `$scope.site.lists`. However, you should note that you should not have this much logic in your controller. Abstract this further by having a single method that returns a promise and hide these details. Your controller should simply have:

```
someService.someMethod().then(function(result) {
  $scope.whatever.push(result);
});
```

Comment: wouldn't the createList now have to return an object to be pushed into site.lists? The way it is right now, it doesn't return anything so I'm not sure what would be pushed into the array

Comment: Then return it! I'm confused why you're having a problem there.

Comment: Ah, I bet you mean because create list is asynchronous?

Comment: @m59 He's not actually passing $scope through to the service, he's passing a property on $scope, i.e. `$scope.site`, so nothing wrong there in my opinion.

Comment: @Beyers As far as I can tell, he isn't passing it as just a value, he's passing it in order to manipulate it (push). The controller should sort of export/import it's data, not actually send its $scope out for manipulation.

Comment: @m59, I should move all the modal code into my service?

Comment: @Batman maybe. A controller is only for wiring data to/from the view. Anything else does not belong. The controller doesn't care about any detail of how the data gets there or what is done with it. The controller only cares where from and where to. The logic to communicate to/from services should be this simple: http://pastebin.com/RxmJnwta

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention: any logic not directly (and I really mean **directly**) related to wiring the ui should be in a service. If you have a code block that does some calculation to figure out how this property and that property should interact, that's a service and isn't the concern of a controller. The controller's job is just to use the service. So, keep things really separated. The reason for this is that the service is available for reuse elsewhere if you need the same logic again.